# Acra ReportSenderException: Error while sending FORM report via Http POST

Tags: android, acra

I am using the following code for generating acra errors.

```
    @ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
        formUri = "http://183.80.72.104:52126/home/acra"
    )
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            ACRA.init(this);
            String androidId = Globals.GetAndroidId(this);          
            //ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("android_id", androidId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error whenever Acra is trying to send data to my server. I have internet permissions set in my manifest. My server is running fine.

```
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending FORM report via Http POST
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:228)
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:173)
12-26 22:28:50.339: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending FORM report via Http POST
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:228)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:173)
12-26 22:28:52.448: E/ACRA(10776):  at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is ACRA-4.5.0?

I can't see where ACRA would be logging the output above. HttpSender:228 has caught an IOException and rebadges it as a ReportSenderException.

I would have expected to see ERROR log of

`Failed to send crash report for " + curFileName`, e

Which would have given the ReportSenderException as well as the underlying IOException.
You need to show the full log, it will detail what the exact problem is.